# Subsetting IF Statement - Why is the following step wrong?

Tags: sas

[image]

The answer to this question is B but I do not see where B is wrong.
Also, I do not understand why A is not wrong since difference is not defined after the first if statement.

Please help!

I chose A but the answer is B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to read the question carefully so you can answer the question that is actually being asked.

The first data step will **NOT** cause SAS to write an **ERROR** message. The syntax is valid.  That does not mean the program is doing the right thing, but that is not what is being asked.  Also the question does not provide enough information to determine if the logic is correct.

The second data step will generate an error because BETWEEN is not valid in a data step outside of a WHERE statement or a WHERE= dataset option.

Comment: Thanks for answering me! I am still a bit confused about option A. The variable difference is not in the original dataset. So when SQL executes line by line and encounters the first if, wouldnt it produce a variable not found error since difference has not yet been defined?

Comment: If you reference a variable that does not yet exist then SAS makes a new variable with that name.  It will set the TYPE of the variable (and the length if the TYPE is CHAR) based on the context where it is first used. If there is no indication of a type in the context then it will be numeric.  So DIFFERENCE will be created as a new numeric variable, so its values will be missing.  Since missing values are smaller than any actual number the subsetting IF statement will have no effect on the results.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this in detail for me! Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`between` is not a SAS operator.  It's legal in SQL contexts (see [this article](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/sqlproc/n0ir3fmhicpfo7n11bfqjn471qkz.htm)), including `where` statements which use SQL operators, but it is not legal in normal data step code.